# XNA 4.0 runs at 30 fps with GF 640M but works fine with integrated Intel card

Tags: c#, xna, nvidia

Every time I run my game using integrated graphics card it works fine at 60 FPS. But sometimes it lags too much when there're a lot of particles on screen.

So I switched to Nvidia GeForce 640M, but framerate keeps at 30 instead of 60. I tried both Reach and HiDef but neither of them could fix the framerate problem. I also tried

```
this.TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(15);
```

but FPS was still 30.

Also tried this but didn't work:

```
public Game1()
{
    graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    graphics.PreparingDeviceSettings += new EventHandler<PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs>(graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings);
}

private void graphics_PreparingDeviceSettings(object sender, PreparingDeviceSettingsEventArgs e)
{
    e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.MultiSampleCount = 4;
    e.GraphicsDeviceInformation.PresentationParameters.PresentationInterval = PresentInterval.One;
}
```

What can I do to fix the framerate on Nvidia graphics card?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the `PresentationParameters.PresentationInterval`?

If I recall correctly, if you set this to `PresentInterval.One`, it "pulls out all the stops" and tries to match the maximum refresh rate.

Been a while since I tinkered with XNA tho...

Comment: No it's still laggy with discrete graphics

Comment: Sorry, does that mean you have tried changing the presentation interval?

Comment: Oh, make sure to try something other than PresentInterval.One too - I'm going from old memories there.

Answer (score 0):

May have something to do with your vsync settings. Try the following

```
graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false;
```